# Hide Customizer Setting on 'ready'

Tags: theme-customizer

Using this code in the console hides the setting as expected:

```
wp.customize.control('sub-footer-content-left').deactivate();
```

However using this in customizer-controls.js doesn't do anything:

```
/**
 * Scripts to alter the behavior of Customizer controls.
 */
 ( function ( $ ) {

     /**
        * Run function when customizer is ready.
        */
        wp.customize.bind('ready', function () {
            wp.customize.control('sub-footer-content-left').deactivate();
        });

 } ) (jQuery);
```

Enqueued to **customize_controls_enqueue_scripts**

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This does work:

`wp.customize.control('sub-footer-content-left').container.toggle();`

However I'm not confident it's the WordPress way.

Comment: Here is a working version of what I am trying to achieve - https://gist.github.com/DannyCooper/22068201b5612723a3750853984b4113. Again, I don't know if this is the WordPress way.